# Combining multiple Ruby Functions

Tags: ruby, regex

Whats an easy way to combine these?
I'm trying to remove integers, floats, and specific words

```
string = "5 basic sent cards by 4.55"

string.delete("0-9.")
string.slice! "sent"
string.slice! "by"

puts string

#desired output: basic cards
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression:

```
string.gsub! /[0-9.]|sent|by/, ''
```

To remove runs of continuous spaces (i.e. `basic  cards` -> `basic cards`), try:

```
string = string.squeeze(' ').strip
```

Comment: thank you! what's a good way to learn ruby? besides the hard way.

Comment: @neil4real Read a book ;) There is no "easy way."

Comment: i'm getting spaces before and after the output on this, any way to remove them?

Comment: `squeeze` won't remove the spaces. Use `strip`.

Comment: I was commenting on the comment that got deleted.

Comment: @theTinMan How so? `p "a     a".squeeze(' ') #=> "a a", but `"a     a".strip #=>"a     a"`

Comment: The comment that was deleted said to use `squeeze` to deal with leading and trailing spaces. I said to use `strip` for those. The answerer then removed the comment and added the chained `squeeze(' ').strip` example.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful using regex: Naive patterns can be very destructive with minor changes to the input:

```
"5 basic sent cards by 4.55".gsub(/[0-9.]|sent|by/, '') # => " basic  cards  "
"5 basic present cards bye 4.55".gsub(/[0-9.]|sent|by/, '') # => " basic pre cards e "

"5 basic sent cards by 4.55".gsub(/[\d.]+|\b(?:sent|by)\b/, '') # => " basic  cards  "
"5 basic present cards bye 4.55".gsub(/[\d.]+|\b(?:sent|by)\b/, '') # => " basic present cards bye "
```

Adding the word-boundary checks protect against in-string matches and false positives.